# Javascript: hiding content when clicking a button for the second time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, button

i'm working on a simple script to make content visible / not visible. 
When clicking on the button the second time the content has to become invisible.

Current project is at: http://mijnronse.be/index.php
See the buttons "Groepen" en "Cadeaubon".

This is the current script:

```js
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".kruisje").click(function(){
        $(".tekstgroepen").hide();
  $(".kruisje").hide();
    });
    $("#knopgroepen").click(function(){
        $(".tekstgroepen").show();
  $(".kruisje").show();
  $(".tekstcadeaubon").hide();
  $(".kruisje2").hide();
    });
 $(".kruisje2").click(function(){
        $(".tekstcadeaubon").hide();
  $(".kruisje2").hide();
    });
  $("#knopcadeaubon").click(function(){
        $(".tekstcadeaubon").show();
  $(".kruisje2").show();
  $(".tekstgroepen").hide();
  $(".kruisje").hide();
    });
 });
</script>
```

So when i click the button #knopgroepen, the text becomes visible as well as the cross button.

I want to know how to make the text and the cross invisible by clicking the button again.

Any help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `.toggle()` instead of `show/hide`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle) instead of [.show()](https://api.jquery.com/show)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".kruisje").click(function () {
        $(".tekstgroepen").hide();
        $(".kruisje").hide();
    });
    $("#knopgroepen").click(function () {
        $(".tekstgroepen").toggle();
        $(".kruisje").toggle();
        $(".tekstcadeaubon").hide();
        $(".kruisje2").hide();
    });
    $(".kruisje2").click(function () {
        $(".tekstcadeaubon").hide();
        $(".kruisje2").hide();
    });
    $("#knopcadeaubon").click(function () {
        $(".tekstcadeaubon").toggle();
        $(".kruisje2").toggle();
        $(".tekstgroepen").hide();
        $(".kruisje").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [**toggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```
$("#knopgroepen").click(function(){
        $(".tekstgroepen").toggle();
        $(".kruisje").toggle();
        $(".tekstcadeaubon").hide();
        $(".kruisje2").hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using show/hide use toggle.

```
$("#knopgroepen").click(function(){
    $(".tekstgroepen").toggle();
    $(".kruisje").toggle();
    $(".tekstcadeaubon").hide();
    $(".kruisje2").hide();
});
```